# This code creates a checker board, Now I have to include numbers 8->1 from top to bottom on both sides of the board

Tags: python, 2d-games

```
def print_beams(num_columns):
    print("+-" * num_columns + "+")

def print_posts(num_columns):
    print("|#| " * num_columns + "| 8")

def print_box_row(num_columns):
    print_posts(num_columns)

def print_hash(num_columns):
    print("| |#" * num_columns + "|") 

def print_letters():
    print(" a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h ")

def print_list():
    print("8")
    print(" ")
    print("7")
    print(" ")
    print("6")
    print(" ")
    print("5")
    print(" ")
    print("4")
    print("3")
    print(" ")
    print("2")
    print(" ")
    print("1")

def print_8_by_8():
        print_letters()
        print_beams(8)
        print_hash(4)

        print_beams(8)
        print_box_row(4)

        print_beams(8)
        print_hash(4)

        print_beams(8)
        print_box_row(4)

        print_beams(8)
        print_hash(4)

        print_beams(8)
        print_box_row(4)

        print_beams(8)
        print_hash(4)

        print_beams(8)
        print_box_row(4)

        print_beams(8)
        print_letters()

print_8_by_8()
```

Comment: What's the extra `8` on print_posts?

Comment: can you show the output you're getting, and a mock-up of the output you want?

Comment: It might be worth thinking about how you are going to store the state of the board (where the pieces are) before cleaning this up too much

Comment: can you use `curses` for output? or is this homework and you can only use what you've already learned?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
row = '-'.join ('+' * 9)
row2 = '|'.join ('# ' * 6);
for i in range (8, 0, -1):
    print (' ', row)
    print (i, row2 [1 + (i % 2 * 2):] [:17] )
print (' ', row)
print ('  ', ' '.join ('abcdefgh') )
```

Output is:

```
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
8 | |#| |#| |#| |#|
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
7 |#| |#| |#| |#| |
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
6 | |#| |#| |#| |#|
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
5 |#| |#| |#| |#| |
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
4 | |#| |#| |#| |#|
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
3 |#| |#| |#| |#| |
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
2 | |#| |#| |#| |#|
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
1 |#| |#| |#| |#| |
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   a b c d e f g h
```